# I got a new house in GTA5 but I’m stuck in between a couch and a lamp. Does anybody know how I could get out

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have tried almost everything. I have tried to climb it and shoot my window but it’s just not working out for me.

Comment: Campaign or Online? Platform? Version? What house? We need more to answer this correctly.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! We'd be more than happy to answer this question, but we need some more details before doing so.

Comment: a complete game restart should fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you kill your character you'll respawn at the nearest hospital in GTA V Story mode, or in a nearby open area if you're in GTA Online. You can use explosives or fire to kill your character.

If you're playing on GTA Online you can also use the "kill yourself" option from the game's interactions menu. Alternatively, you could join a GTA Online heist, race, deathmatch or other event to be teleported out of the area you're trapped in.

If you're playing GTA V story mode you can switch to another character, wait about a minute, and switch back.

Lastly, you could quit the game, or switch between GTA V Story and GTA Online. Both of witch would spawn your character in the nearest open area.